# SKSpriteNode Subclass Position issue

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm developing a game where you have a character. The character is a subclass of an SKSpriteNode:

```
class Character: SKSpriteNode {

init() {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "character")
    super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.white, size: texture.size())
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.zPosition = 10
    self.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.name = "character"
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("Touch!")

    // Create small +1 sprite
    let plusNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plus1Node")
    plusNode.zPosition = 10000 //To make sure its always in front
    plusNode.position = self.position
    self.addChild(plusNode)
}
```

The character is added to the game via GameScene.swift:

```
    func spawnCharacter() {
        //Random postion for the pigs
        let randomX = Functions().randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: -140, secondNum: 140)
        let randomY = Functions().randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: -240, secondNum: 240)

        let newCharacter = Character()
        newCharacter = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: randomY)
        gameArea!.addChild(newCharacter)
    }
```

When the player taps the character a little "+1" node is spawned to show the player that he has touched the character. I want that +1 node to be spawned on top of the character, but it's placed way off - like multiple points away.

If I move the +1 code to the GameScene (just after the character is created and added to the scene the position is spot on).

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are adding plusNode to a wrong node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PulzeNode.position = CGpoint.zero
```

As you add it to the character, it should be at the origin of parent node